# $ax$ is arithmetic; $a^x$ is geometric; $\frac{a}{x}$ is harmonic; what's $x^a$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

I know the following terminology: $ax$ is arithmetic; $a^x$ is geometric; $\frac{a}{x}$ is harmonic.

What is $x^a$ called? Is there an equivalent name for progressions of the form $t_x=x^a$, where $a$ is constant?

Comment: This is just a power function. If $a\in\mathbb{N}_0$ then it would be a monomial/polynomial.

Comment: @PeterForeman OK, thanks. Can power functions and/or polynomials then be considered 'siblings' to arithmetic, geometric and harmonic functions, or are they in some other relationship?

Comment: @PeterForeman I mean is the set 'polynomial functions' superordinate to (i.e. the parent set of) arithmetic, geometric and harmonic functions; or is it coordinate with them (i.e. a sibling)? If the latter, to what superordinate set do they all belong?

Comment: There is no group which includes all of these functions. They are just commonly used functions in sequences. It is not true that any of the stated functions are siblings/children of the polynomial as clearly $x^a$ and $a^x$ for example are unrelated.